# Under which scenarios would $R^2$ increase the most when adding a new predictor (linear independent, uncorrelated, orthogonal)?

Tags: least-squares

From what I know, $R^2$ is weakly increasing as you add more predictors to a linear regression model.

It can never decrease. If it did, then something went wrong with solving least squares. The worst case would be adding the new predictor doesn't change $R^2$ at all, which would occur if you added a predictor that was a linear combination of the original ones.

Say you regressed $y$ on $x_1$ and you obtain $R^2_1 = k$. Now say you add in $x_2$.
If you want to maximize $R^2$ on the multiple regression model, would it be better to choose $x_2$ such that it's:

(1) Linear independent of $x_1$ (assume $x_2$ is not uncorrelated with $x_1$, and further assume it's not orthogonal with $x_1$)

(2) Uncorrelated with $x_1$ (which also always implies (1). This can also sometimes imply (3), but assume the $x_2$ isn't orthogonal but uncorrelated)

(3) Orthogonal to $x_1$ (which also always implies (1). This can also sometimes imply (2), but assume $x_2$ is not uncorrelated with $x_1$)

Which of these would give the largest increase in $R^2$ from the univariate regression model, or can no generality be made?

On second thought, when I think about this, I feel like it's highly dependent on what $y$ is and its relationship to $x_1$. So I think I'm looking for a more open ended answer that covers different cases for $y$, if possible.

Comment: The answer is none of the above, for the reason you give at the end: the increase in $R^2$ measures how correlated the residuals of $y$ are with the residuals of $x_2.$  You don't need to break it down into cases.